# Add custom page number when citing bibliography entry

Tags: bibliographies

Suppose I have the following bibliography set up in my LaTeX document.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{Cite1}
Peter Jackson
\textit{Some random article name}.
Journal name,\textbf{29}, p339-349, 1968.
\end{thebibliography}
```

I now wish to cite this reference, for example

```
Hello \cite{Cite1}
```

which then displays as

```
Hello [1]
```

I however, want to include in this specific citation that this comes from page 342, i.e I want to display something like

```
Hello [1, pg. 342]
```

How can I go about doing that?

Comment: Just write `\cite[pg. 342]{Cite1}`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `[pg. 342]` as option to the command `\cite`: `\cite[pg. 342]{Cite1}`.

Please see the following MWE (See the code changing I did, marked with `<======`):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

Hello \cite{Cite1} 

Hello \cite[pg. 342]{Cite1} % <=========================================

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{Cite1}
Peter Jackson
\textit{Some random article name}.
Journal name,\textbf{29}, p339-349, 1968.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]